# Many to many relationship between tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have the following problem. I have one table Games with unique ID (primary key) and one table Users with unique ID(primary key). The problem is that many users can play one game and one game can be played by many users. I read, that I need one more table to connect the two tables, but I am not sure how to do it. My idea so far is to create another table Games_users where to store gameID and userID both as PK, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You read, where?  PS Time to read a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & database design.)

Comment: Have a look on the chapter "Modeling of different link types" in the book ["Programming with databases"](https://www.amazon.com/dp/2956300806/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many-to-Many relationships needing an associate table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466222/many-to-many-relationships-needing-an-associate-table)

Comment: (Obviously,) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct: You have to create a bridge table between the two entities related many-to-many and put the GameId and UserId.

Remember also to set the foreign keys in order to keep consistency in your database